# wordsAPI fetch returns 200 status with no data javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have just subbed to **wordsAPI** https://www.wordsapi.com/

and pasted the code to fetch data straight from their Docs:

```
const getDefinition = async (text) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/${text}/definitions`, {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "MYAPIKEY"
            }
        })
        console.log(res)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

the response object looks as such:

> body: (...)
> bodyUsed: false
> headers: Headers {}
> ok: true
> redirected: false
> status: 200
> statusText: "OK"
> type: "cors"
> url: "https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/something/synonyms"
> [[Prototype]]: Response

I get back a 200 but the response has no data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `res.json()` to fetch data:

```
const getDefinition = async (text) => {
try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/${text}/definitions`, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "MYAPIKEY"
        }
    })
    const mainData = await res.json();
    console.log(mainData)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    }
}
```